# Question about partitions with a single element and equivalence relations

Tags: elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I couldn't find a formal definition of a partition but I found this picture on the [Bell numbers wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_numbers).

[image]

You can see there are no partitions with a single element, it confused me, why a partition with a single element seemingly isn't considered a partition?

For example in the case of 5 elements, why doesn't $\{x\}$ or $\{\{x,y\},\{z\}\}$ considered partitions ?

Comment: Wikipedia has this: [Partitions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_a_set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"You can see there are no partitions with a single element"?? I see that the last partition in your picture does have a single element, namely the set of all five elements.

In more detail: If the 5 elements of the set that you're partitioning are named 1,2,3,4,5, then the first partition in your picture is $\{\{1\},\{2\},\{3\},\{4\},\{5\}\}$, which has 5 elements, each of which is a one-element set.  The last partition in your picture is $\{\{1,2,3,4,5\}\}$, which has just one element, and that one element is a five-element set.

Concerning the last sentence of your question, $\{\{x,y\},\{z\}\}$ is a partition, but it is a partition of a 3-element set, $\{x,y,z\}$, not of a 5-element set.  Since a partition is always a set of sets, $\{x\}$ would be a partition only if $x$ is a set, and then $\{x\}$ is a partition of the set $x$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how exactly the figure relates to partitions... A partition of a set is a collection of subsets such that any element of the set belongs to exactly one subset. There is nothing forbidding one (or all) of those subsets from having only one element.

Comment: Well I see the wiki says otherwise: "{ {1}, {2} } is not a partition of {1, 2, 3} because none of its blocks contains 3; however, it is a partition of {1, 2}." so a partition must partition all the elements of the set.

Comment: And how does that contradict what I wrote?

Comment: I guess what I meant by "one element" isn't what you meant, I meant for example {{1}} as a partition, I see now what I did wrong.